# How do I collapse an Either in PureScript?

Tags: purescript, either

I have an object of type `Either String (Either String Int)`. I would like to collapse it to an object of type `Either String Int`.

Is there a provided function for this in PureScript?

Comment: I don't know purescript, but this is `join` (with `Either String` as the monad) in Haskell. Maybe that helps?

Comment: @luqui yes, it is more-or-less the same as Haskell

Comment: @sdgfsdh Just a tip, purescript's typed holes can search for definitions that match their type:
check out http://try.purescript.org/?gist=7552f9f7edeae7f58e5114c9a479fb53&backend=core as an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the same as Haskell:

```hs
import Prelude
import Data.Either

let a = Left "a" :: Either String (Either String Int)
let b = Right (Left "b") :: Either String (Either String Int)
let c = Right (Right 123) :: Either String (Either String Int)

join a -- Left "a"
join b -- Left "b"
join c -- Right 123
```

Comment: Consider accepting this answer so the question shows up as answered.